# Output impedance for a Buck converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter

Is 763uOhms @603kHz considered to be bad (very low) when it comes to output impedance. Would it be a dead short? My design for a Buck Converter shows this as its output impedance. How low is ok ?
[image]

Comment: Only you can answer how low is enough according to your specifications.

Comment: 763 uV is a voltage and not an output impedance.

Comment: It is meant to be Ohms so change to 763uV to 763uOhms. The design is to charge a pack of super capacitors. I was asking if there would be any disadvantage to having a very low output impedance ? Would the buck converter see this as a dead short and act accordingly ?

Comment: *How low is ok ?* How long is a piece of string? Usually a switched converter provides the supply voltage for another circuit. What is that other circuit? What are the requirements on the power supply ripple and noise on the supply of that other circuit. A resistive heater doesn't care. A GPS receiver is much more sensitive. Never ask "is this OK" if you don't specify what the "OK requirement" is (and if you know, you don't need to ask).

Comment: *The design is to charge a pack of super capacitors* AHA! That information should have been in the question. So how much do you think a supercap cares about supply ripple?

Comment: The Power Supply is a server PSU the buck converter steps down a 12V to 8V. Sorry i was not sure what more would be required to answer it. Let me if more details are required.

Comment: Are you aware that you need a buck converter with a **current limiting mode**? You cannot connect an uncharged supercap to a buck converter, it will be seen as a **dead short** and the buck converter will **shut off** (if it is any good). Go watch Julian Ilett's youtube channel: https://www.youtube.com/user/julius256 he has lots of  videos about charging supercaps from buck converters.

Comment: The output impedance graphs you show are **completely irrelevant**! What they show is the **small signal output impedance** and that applies to **small changes** in the supply voltage as a result of small changes in the load current, you can call this AC behavior of a buck converter. For charging supercaps you need to focus on the **DC behavior**. For that you need **current limiting**.

Comment: Yes the Buck converter [LTC3868](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3868fe.pdf) is limited to 70A

Comment: *Yes the Buck converter LTC3868 is limited to 70A* **Yes and no**. You clearly don't understand this subject well enough. That's OK but then please first **research into the subject**. That 70 A is set by an external shunt resistor and is used to **protect** the external MOSFETs and make sure that the **inductor** doesn't saturate. This is **not** adjustable current limiting. For charging supercaps you need adjustable current limiting. An LTC3868 **does not have that**. Do what Julian does in his videos: use a ready-made converter module.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117415/discussion-between-george-and-bimpelrekkie).

Comment: There is very little information to learn about these buck converters other than those mentioned in the datasheet. I am using the LTPowerCad to get the initial schematic. From what i learned around asking in forums is that the Supercaps just needs to be CC and limited to desired current levels and using microcontroller stop the charging when the desired voltage is reached. I did look at off the shelf chargers but those are limited to 10A charge current or so.